# Coordinates of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, coordinates

I am going to create a selection 'lasso' that the user can use to select portions of a table. I figured that positioning a div over the region is far easier than trying to manipulate the cell borders.

If you don't understand what I mean, open up a spread sheet and drag over a region. I want the div to align perfectly with the cell borders.

I have a very good idea of how to do this, but **how would I get the (x,y) coordinates (screen position) of a table cell (td)?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset) along with [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height) and [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width) if necessary.

```
var td = $(someTDReference);
var pos = td.offset();
pos.bottom = pos.top + td.height();
pos.right = pos.left + td.width();
// pos now contains top, left, bottom, and right in pixels
```

**Edit:** Not <strike>`.position()`</strike>, use `.offset()`.  Updated above.

**Edit:** Changed `pos.width()` to `td.width()`

Comment: Nice, +1. Didn't know about position containing right and bottom now. Did you mean td.width() in line 4 though?

Comment: @jackrugile - `.position()` still returns only `top` and `left`.  The lines of code that follow in my example add `bottom` and `right` to the object returned from `.position()` by adding `.height()` and `.width()` to `top` and `left` respectively.  I just do this for convenience.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are doing now. My bad, misunderstood. Nice method for all four locations.

Answer (score 3):

Hey you should be able to do it like this (jsFiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/jackrugile/YKHkX/

```
$('td').hover(function(){
    var xPos = Math.floor($(this).offset().left);
    var yPos = Math.floor($(this).offset().top);
});
```

The `Math.floor` gets rid of the crazy decimals and makes it easier to work with in my opinion. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

you can use pageX and pageY to trackdown the mouse cursor x , y

```
$("#your_div").mouseover(function(e))
{
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
}
```

you can set the div border to highlight the div on mouseover simply by

```
$("#your_div").css("border","1px solid black");
```

this will kinda show current div selectable effect...

that if if the div is

> position:fixed and then you can read its left and top property

hope that helps you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is not what I want to do. I just need to figure out how to get the onscreen coordinates of a td.

Comment: i think if you make a div with display:none and position:fixed inside that td where left: inherit and top: inherit then you can be certain where that td is on the screen by reading the left and top .. sorry i dont know further then that may be some one posts a better reply. cheers

Answer (score 0):

For those who doesn't want to use jquery:

```
var coordinates = td.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(coordinates.left, coordinates.top, coordinates.right, coordinates.bottom);
```