# Get position of an element relatively to one ancestor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have the following HTML code (it's an example):

```
<div id="site_header_container" class="site_bar_container">
    <div id="site_header">
        <div id="header_logo_container">
                     <a class="sliced" id="header_logo" href="/">&nbsp;</a>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

With several CSS applied. Basically in the div with `id="site_header_container"`, there is a `background-image`.  I would like to know which top and left values the `<a>` element has inside the `site_header_container`.

So, how can I given one element, call it, **ancestor**, and another element call it **descendant**, know the **position of descendant relatively to its ancestor** in **pure** Javascript (I don't want to use any libraries) and it has to work just in Chrome?

Comment: Find the location of each and use *MATH*. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255019/coordinates-of-html-elements

Comment: @Diodeus the OP said no jQuery

Comment: How is jQuery not "pure" JavaScript? You mean JavaScript you write entirely yourself?

Comment: @ithcy because it's not standardized (cf. promises for example). But I guess the OP meant plain JavaScript (no library dependency).

Comment: @Christophe it's just funny, because in order to solve this in a way that works reliably across browsers and layout scenarios, OP must eventually end up with a crippled version of [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js) :)

Comment: @ithcy :-) you have a point here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) to reciev the position of the child and parent element and than subtract parent's coordinates from child's.

```
var coords = element.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(coords.top, coords.right, coords.bottom, coords.left);
```

If parents coordienates are (left)500, (top)500 and child's 550, 550, child's coordinates relative to its parent are 50, 50

http://codepen.io/dollseb/pen/oilyH

Comment: is getBoundingClientRect always trustful? I mean, if the element is absolute positioned and so on, will it work too?

Comment: I created a little test case and played around whit it. feel free to do the same. :) http://codepen.io/dollseb/pen/oilyH

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) explains how to do it. Starting from your a element, you need to climb up the DOM hierarchy and add the `offsetTop` and `offsetHeight` properties of each parent until you reach the ancestor.

Comment: **tl;dr:** cycling through offsetParents won’t work – Adding the `offsetTop` of each _parent_ will give you incorrect results, seeing as `offsetTop` is relative to the _offsetParent_. If taking this approach, you would need to iterate through the offsetParent of every offsetParent etc, but then you risk missing the relevant ancestor (to which you want to know the relative position).